# Caddyfile Subdomain with Multiple Proxies

Tags: caddy, caddyfile

i am new to using caddy and i am trying to figure out how to create a subdomain that can proxy to different endpoints based on path.

for example for a subdomain called `pets` in the domain `my-website.com`. i want to route the path `/cats` to `serviceA` and `/dogs` to `serviceB`.

i have tried this configuration:

```
pets.my-website.com {
    proxy /cats http://serviceA:80
    proxy /dogs http://serviceB:80
}
```

but this does not seem to work.

can anyone see what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

the problem was caused because the path it was forwarding to the service included the url path prefix. e.g. `/cats`.

i thought it would automatically remove this prefix but it doesnt. **the solution is as follows:**

```
pets.my-website.com {
    proxy /cats http://serviceA:80 {
        without /cats
    }
    proxy /dogs http://serviceB:80 {
        without /dogs
    }
}
```